# live drawing on image in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy, satellite

I'm trying to plot the satellite ground track on a map currently I'm using cartopy, matplotlib

the pass of the satellite is calculated separately and saved in.CSV file when I try to plot the path the result is great and accurate but it's done once (the full path is plotted as a whole)

[image]

but I need to plot it point by point and update the figure each time a new point is added.

this is the code I used in this problem:

```
# imports
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.feature.nightshade import Nightshade

import datetime

# reading CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("longlat.csv")

# converting column data to list of latitudes and longitudes
latitudes = data['Latitude'].tolist()
longitudes = data['Longitude'].tolist()

# Create a new figure, or activate an existing figure.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15.2, 8.2))
# Add an Axes to the current figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# time to set the Nightshade to
# date = datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 8, 20, 9, 00)
date = datetime.datetime.now()

ax.stock_img()
# add Nightshade tp the map according to the time
ax.add_feature(Nightshade(date, alpha=0.3))

# set the x and y limits of the current axes.
plt.xlim([-180, 180])
plt.ylim([-90, 90])

# Configure the grid lines displayed on the map with the labels om x amd y.
plt.grid(True, color='w', linestyle="dotted", alpha=0.3, linewidth=1)
plt.xticks(range(-180, 181, 30), ['-180°W', '-150°W', '-120°W', '-90°W', '-60°W', '-30°W', '0°', '30°E', '60°E',
                                  '90°E', '120°E', '150°E', '180°E'])
plt.yticks(range(-90, 91, 30), ['-90°S', '-60°S', '-30°S', '0°', '30°N', '60°N', '90°N'])

# Adjust the padding between and around subplots.
plt.tight_layout()


def plot_city(cities_list):
    """
    function plot cities location points on the map
    :param cities_list: list like object
    list of cities to plo on the map ['city name', longitude, latitude]
    :return: None
    """
    for city in cities_list:
        # plot city on the map
        plt.plot(city[1], city[2], marker="o", markersize=5, markeredgecolor="blue", markerfacecolor="green")
        # plot city name on the map according to it's location
        plt.text(city[1] - 1, city[2] - 1, city[0], horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=8, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())


cities = [['Cairo', 29.35, 30.03333], ['Moscow', 37.618423, 55.751244], ['Paris', 2.349014, 48.864716]]

# sample city location plotting  (cairo)
plot_city(cities)


def satellite_plot(longitudes, latitudes):
    # plot the satellite moving line
    plt.plot(longitudes, latitudes, 'red', linestyle="dotted", linewidth=2, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
    satellite = plt.plot(longitudes, latitudes, marker="o", markersize=5,
                         markeredgecolor="blue", markerfacecolor="green")
    line = satellite.pop(0)
    line.remove()


satellite_plot(longitudes, latitudes)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you will have to create loop which plot only some part of data - first only `[:1]`, in next loop `[:2]`, in next loop `[:3]`, etc, it may need also to sleep few milliseconds (to slow down animation) and read new data, and repeate all. You may also use `AnimFuncion()` for this but still you have to create function which change data (add new point) and it will plot it.

Comment: that's a good point but the main problem is to update the figure after reading the new point how can I do this

Comment: if you find `AnimFuncion` then you should see than you can use that plot give `ax` and it have `set_xdata()`, `set_ydata()` to replace previouse data (ie. `[:1]`) with new data (ie. `[:2]`)

Comment: sorry, it is [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) and somewhere in matplotlib documentation was example.

Comment: minimal example [simple-anim-py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py), more in [gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#animation)

Comment: Great information I'll try it now